# Why do I get HTTP request when using WebSockets?

Tags: html, websocket

I've written a vanilla WebSocket client in JavaScript that connects to a localhost via 8080 port and sends out '***hello server***'.

My server is witten in Python using standart **socket** package. When I connect to it using `WebSocket`, the server receives a HTTP request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3030
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: g3y2hDw5WpZYKUwIrsGYaw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
```

... and it doesn't receive the original ***'hello server'*** message that was supposed to be sent by the `WebSocket` connection.

I'm confused; are regular sockets and WebSockets not the same thing? Why do I get HTTP request instead of original message?

Comment: I am not at home so I can't make sure, but afaik the WebSockets works by the client sending an "Upgrade" HTTP req which the server should respond with HTTP 101 Switching Protocol. THEN they go on to establish a WebSockets connection. There is also a complicated Sec-WebSocket-Key and -Accept thing that the best way to do it is by using a dedicated library.

Comment: If you want to use WebSocket in python, have a look at [Autobahn](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython)

Answer (score 0):

In short, no web sockets are not just sockets.  They are a new http-like protocol on top of TCP.  Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket for a brief overview or the RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455 for details.

Comment: WebSockets are not "http-like". They have an HTTP compatible handshake (so they can co-exist better with existing infrastructure and services), but after that they are a bidirectional, full-duplex, low-latency transport with support for raw binary data which is not at all like HTTP.